# Can generics infer a related type?

Tags: java, generics

Given

```
public class Foo {
    public static class FooBuilder { ... }
}
```

I want to write a method on a third class that returns Foo, given Foo.FooBuilder.class

i.e.

```
Foo f = x.make(Foo.FooBuilder.class, someData);
```

Is it possible to declare a signature using generics that can imply the return type? Is there some language feature that lets me say "type U is outer class of type T"?

Obviously, it is possible to specify that type extends, or is the base of, a generic type (`U extends T` or `U super T`, respectively) but I am looking for `U outer T` which is, I think, more than Java can offer, even indirectly, at least in 1.7, which I am targeting.

So far, I have simply declared both inner and outer types, which works but is a wider definition than I am after and looks clumsy too.

```
public <TYPE,BUILDER> TYPE make(Class<BUILDER> builderClass, Map<String,Object> data) {
    // Construct TYPE
}
```

Is there a way to infer TYPE without explicitly providing a template parameter?

Comment: It's *well worth* consulting the JavaDoc when you have a question like this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`Class#getDeclaringClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaringClass--) method that may work in your case.
Quoting the docs:

> If the class or interface represented by this Class object is a member of another class, returns the Class object representing the class in which it was declared.

**EDIT:**

After the clarification of OP, here is the new suggestion:

You create an generic interface to mark all your nested classes:

```
public interface Nested<P> {

}
```

Then you apply it to your `Foo.Bar` class like this:

```
public class Foo {

    public static class Bar implements Nested<Foo> {

    }

}
```

Then in your factory you can have the following:

```
public <P> P make(Class<? extends Nested<P>> clazz, Map<String, Object> someData) {
    // do whatever you need to do
    return (P) clazz.getDeclaringClass();
}
```

However, with this construct, there is not way to validate it your nested class is the real class, declared when implementing the generic interface.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is not how I get Class<Foo> from Class<Foo.Bar> (that is trivial) but, using generics, how do I specify a method that returns an object of type Foo, if the template is only told about Foo.Bar.

Comment: @SarahPhillips I edited my answer, maybe it can give you some hints.